# How to access a memer variable a with symbol

Tags: php, stdclass

I have a property of a PHP stdClass which starts with an `@` symbol (according to my  debugger). How do I access its value?

```
@averageBaseRate = "22.49"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use curly braces:

```
$obj->{'@averageBaseRate'}
```

It's the [complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) applied to an object.

Using that syntax, you can use any name you want for the member variable.
One can even put really strange Unicode characters in the name.